# why i am getting undefined value

Tags: javascript, scope, this, global

I have this code when i run it displays undefined. However we can access global property with this keyword.

```
 var firstName = "Peter",
        lastName = "Ally";

        function showFullName () {
        // "this" inside this function will have the value of the window object
        // because the showFullName () function is defined in the global scope, just like the firstName and lastName
        alert (this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
        }
        showFullName ();
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gerexi/1/edit?js,output — I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: me neither its ok

Comment: In strict mode, it shoul just throw an error. If this is placed _inside_ another function then it would display "undefined undefined".

Comment: I am getting undefined. Please check in fiddle.

Comment: @user1989488 Fiddle is obviously not running the code in global scope, in that case.

Answer (score 1):

This works if executed properly (replaced `alert` with `console.log` for easier examples)

```js
var firstName = "Peter",
    lastName = "Ally";

function showFullName () {
  // "this" inside this function will have the value of the window object
  console.log("this and window are the same thing", this === window);
  
  // because the showFullName () function is defined in the global scope, just like the firstName and lastName
  console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
}

showFullName();
```

If this is placed *in functional scope* it will not work, however - presumably JS Fiddle does something like that

```js
(function() {
  var firstName = "Peter",
        lastName = "Ally";

    function showFullName () {
      // "this" inside this function will still have the value of the window object
      console.log("this and window are the same thing", this === window);
      
      // however firstName and lastName are not goint to be attached to it because they are in functional scope
      console.log("the names are still reachable", firstName, lastName)
      
      //but not attached to the window object (which "this" points to)
      console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
    }

    showFullName();
})();
```

Do note that with if you have [strict mode enabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) then `this` will be `undefined` instead of `window` and the code will produce an error

```js
var firstName = "Peter",
    lastName = "Ally";

function showFullName () {
  "use strict";
  // "this" inside this function will now have the value "undefined"
  console.log("'this' is actually 'undefined'", this);
  console.log("the actual value 'undefined', not a string", typeof this);
  
  // the following line will throw a TypeError because it's trying to get a property from "undefined"
  console.log(this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
}

showFullName();
```

Answer (score -1):

Normaly use `window` keyword instead. `this` is independent on place where was funciton declared but is dependent on place where was (and how) called.

```
var firstName = "Peter",
    lastName = "Ally";

function showFullName () {
    alert (window.firstName + " " + window.lastName);
}
showFullName();
```

Answer (score -1):

So i came to know that, when we use strict mode, this keyword holds the value of undefined in global functions.
In strict mode, however, the value of this remains at whatever it was set to when entering the execution context, so, in the following case, this will default to undefined:

```
 function f2(){
      "use strict"; // see strict mode
      return this;
    }

    f2() === undefined;
```

So, in strict mode, if this was not defined by the execution context, it remains undefined.I have taken this code snippet from MDN.

So in my case value is not appearing in fiddle.But it would be reason which is pointed out by @vlaz. Thanks @vlaz

Comment: If you _had_ strict mode enabled than the code above would have thrown an error.